# How to replace certain values of array meeting a condition with a list of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 4x4 numpy array (dtype = object) and I would like to replace wherever there is a 0, with a list of 1-4. I am able to replace the 0's with a set of 1-4 like below, but not a list, any idea why and how to overcome this?

```html
def replace_zeroes(arr):
    fullSet = {1, 2, 3, 4}
    lst = [1,2,3,4]
    arr_c = arr.copy()
    arr_c = arr_c.astype('object')
    np.place(arr_c, arr_c==0, fullSet)

    return arr_c
```

Attached are the outputs, first shows it works successfully with a set but I'm not sure what it does with a list?

Also, will np.argwhere(arr_c==0) help in any way, by getting the indexes and then replacing with a list? Not exactly sure how to use it though.

[[image: As can be seen below, it works with a set]

[image: It does not work with a list]

Edit, original array is:

```html
arr = [[1,2,4,0],
       [1,3,1,5],
       [0,3,5,3],
       [1,0,1,0]]
       
arr = np.array(arr)
```

Expected output is instead of a set with 1,2,3,4, I would like a list of [1,2,3,4] wherever the 0s are.

Comment: Could you share the original array and what is your expected output?

Comment: Hi, just added the original array, thanks.

Comment: the same problem has `arr_c[ arr_c == 0 ] = lst` but works `arr_c[ arr_c == 0 ] = fullSet`

Comment: I could do this only in `pandas.DataFrame` - `df = df.applymap(lambda x: (lst if x == 0 else x))
`

Comment: because there is zero so I could use `or` - `df = df.applymap(lambda x: (x or lst))`

Comment: digging in source code of `applymap` I found information that it is substitution for `np.vectorize` but I had no luck to resolve this problem with `np.vectorize`

Comment: hmm so I guess there is no way to do this in numpy? does anyone know why? it's strange what happens when you do try, it places ints in place of the 0 but not a list.